# Retrieve related caller instance possible ? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

There are two related django models, for example:

```
from django.db import models

class Shipping(models.Model):
    def calc_by_order(self):
        # calculate shipping by order's total
        return SHIPPING_RATE * ??? # self.order_set.<something>

class Order(models.Model):
    shipping = models.ForeignKey(Shipping)
    total = models.DecimalField()
```

Curious, whether possible in `Shipping.calc_by_order` optionally back-reference caller instance and use it for its methods access:

```
order = Order.objects.last()
print order.shipping.calc_by_order()
```

I can explicitly pass order's instance to `calc_by_order`, but interested if this is really necessary.

I'm also aware `calc_by_order` method could be defined on `Order` model, but that's not an option.

Comment: Why isn't it an option to define it on Order? That would definitely make the most sense.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because Order is a 3rd party framework's model and may not be modified. I can patch it at a runtime, but that's a bit "dirty" solution. I can also define and work with its subclass, but doubt this would be worth the extra table and database query for such simple case.

Comment: Note the foreign key relation in the question's example is achieved through framework's API allowing define additional model fields in settings.py. Just fields, not methods.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no extra Django infrastructure to support requested feature. It boils down to Python's way of code introspection, available with `inspect` standard module and its methods. Definitely not a production solution, monkey-patching or subclassing seems superior in comparison.